# System.Random behaving very strangely; numbers displayed are not the numbers being operated on

Tags: haskell, random

I needed to generate some random numbers for testing purposes. I have never used Data.Random before. I needed to do many tests and I would not know the amount of numbers I would need in advance, but I would know that they should fall into a certain bound. I wrote the function:

```
import System.Random

f k = (\(x,y) -> x*y < (10^k) && x*y >0 )

rands n g k = take n $ filter (\(x,y) -> x*y < (10^k) && x*y >0 ) (zip a b) 
    where a = randomRs (1::Int, 10^k-1) ga 
          b = randomRs (1::Int, 10^k-1) gb
          (ga, gb) = split $ mkStdGen g
```

and began to test things using the numbers it generated. I began to notice strange things when using this function:

```
testRands n k = do
    g1 <- randomIO
    g2 <- randomIO
    let r = rands n (mkStdGen g1, mkStdGen g2) k
    putStrLn $ show r 
    putStrLn $ show $ map (\(x,y) -> x*y < 10^k && x*y >0) r  
    putStrLn $ show $ map (\(x,y) -> x*y) r
    putStrLn $ show $ maximum $ map (\(x,y) -> x*y) r

*Main> testRands 4 7
[(6193574,9385226),(9634973,5475375),(5070277,7408626),(3801396,5652588)]
[True,True,True,True]
[4353660,6993107,2038586,4030960]
6993107
```

I then copy the numbers it generated and paste them back into GHCI and call the exact same predicate function on all of them:

```
*Main> map (f 7) [(6193574,9385226),(9634973,5475375),(5070277,7408626),(3801396,5652588)]
[False,False,False,False]
```

This makes no sense and I don't even know where to start trying to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your program, you are explicitly generating values of type `Int`, in the lines:

```
where a = randomRs (1::Int, 10^k-1) ga 
      b = randomRs (1::Int, 10^k-1) gb
```

If you are on a 32-bit machine, then multiplication of the generated numbers can lead to an overflow. For example:

```
> 6193574 * 9385226 :: Int
4353660
```

The literals themselves are overloaded, though. So if you paste them into GHCi, then they're defaulted to the (unbounded) `Integer` type, where they do not overflow:

```
> 6193574 * 9385226 :: Integer
58128091737724
```

This explains the difficult outcomes of applying the predicate.

So either generate `Integer` rather than `Int`, or add a type annotation stating that the list you pass is `[Int]` rather than `[Integer]` to make the results match.

Comment: Damn type errors, I threw that `:: Int` in there because it was giving me `ambiguous type variable` and forgot about it.

Answer (score 4):

You are running a 32-bit GHC:

```
Prelude Data.Int> uncurry (*) (6193574,9385226) :: Int32
4353660
```

So, since your `Int`s are 32 bits, the product is smaller than the limit due to overflow.

```
a = randomRs (1::Int, 10^k-1) ga
```

But when you

```
*Main> map (f 7) [(6193574,9385226),(9634973,5475375),(5070277,7408626),(3801396,5652588)]
[False,False,False,False]
```

the type is not constrained to `Int`, and hence defaults to `Integer`, so there is no overflow, and the product larger than the limit..

Comment: Why did you write the multiplication as `uncurry (*) (x,y)` rather than `x * y` ?

Comment: Because I copy-pasted the pair with the numbers, writing `uncurry (*)` in front of it was less work than editing the `*` in the middle.

Comment: Like "I had a dish with way too much curry directly before"?